# How to add header using interceptor in micronaut

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut

I use micronaut and kotlin. So I trying to add header to request to other service using interceptor. Can you give me example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I trying to add header to request to other service using
> interceptor. Can you give me example?

Here is an example from https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientFilter:

```
@Filter("/repos/**") 
class BintrayFilter implements HttpClientFilter {

    final String username;
    final String token;

    BintrayFilter(
            @Value("${bintray.username}") String username, 
            @Value("${bintray.token}") String token ) { 
        this.username = username;
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.proceed(
                request.basicAuth(username, token) 
        );
    }
}
```

In the `doFilter` method there you can do whatever you like with the request, including adding headers to it.

**EDIT**

The question indicates Kotlin is being used.  Here is the Kotlin counterpart which is available at the same url as lined above:

```
@Filter("/repos/**") 
internal class BintrayFilter(
        @param:Value("\${bintray.username}") val username: String, 
        @param:Value("\${bintray.token}") val token: String) : HttpClientFilter {

    override fun doFilter(request: MutableHttpRequest<*>, chain: ClientFilterChain): Publisher<out HttpResponse<*>> {
        return chain.proceed(
                request.basicAuth(username, token) 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you specifically asked about doing it with an interceptor (filter), but for reference, there are other ways to populate request headers that for some use cases will be more simple than using filters.  It may be that what you are doing really does call for a filter.  Other approaches are documented at https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientHeaders.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I understood correctly, the Micronaut API does not provide the possibility to directly add additional headers to a request. You can only add attributes, which you can't later access from the response level.

Comment: " If I understood correctly, the Micronaut API does not provide the possibility to directly add additional headers to a request." - I don't believe that is correct.

Comment: Yea, I found out that it is indeed incorrect. You can do `request.mutate().header()`.